# Parameter in parameter in services.yml

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony5 and what I want to achive is to use a parameter in another parameter. Is it possible? Of course I've searchd for it, but did not find a solution. For example:

```
media:
    extendions:
        - pdf
    path: '%kernel.project_dir%/media/'


incomingPdf:
    #path: '%kernel.project_dir%/media/incoming/pdf'
    path: '@=parameter("media")["path"]incoming/pdf'
```

It says, expressions is not allowed in parameters.

In `incomingPdf` I want to use defined `media['path']`s value.

Comment: In the services config you could add under *parameters* your media path. For example `parameters: app.media.dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/media/'` then use that anywhere else in multiple places in the services config with `%app.media.dir%` for example.. Unless this is out of the scope you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know how can I use it under services section. I just want do it in the parameters section like a variable. Instead of the not allowed expression.

Comment: You can, but as a "flat" parameter only. What's not supported is [using nested parameters](https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/symfony/blob/f5c6abf42b67b6988c90fa1f0b61f15faae1a745/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L824) (arrays, in practice) and expressions to resolve them. The following is perfectly acceptable: `media.path: '%kernel.project_dir%/media'` and `incomingPdf: '%media.path%/incoming/pdf'`. If you think about it, you are already doing that by using `%kernel.project_dir%`.

Comment: @that works, but not as I want. So, I can not use nested... anyway, your solution will do the job. thx.

Comment: To be fair, is what @Bossman was saying as well. Here's the [original ticket](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33603) if you are interested on the background explanation.

Comment: @msg, don't worry, it happens to me in real life too *lol*.